# Alamofire .post api error: Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire

Using Alamofire for .post api, api giving data in postman but not in my code. Posting below the code, please guide what wrong i am doing here:

```
// API calling method:

parameters = [
        "Address" : "" as AnyObject,
        "Name" :  "" as AnyObject,
        "ServiceID" : "" as AnyObject,
        "Rating" :  "" as AnyObject,
        "Price" :  "" as AnyObject
    ]

    let headers: Dictionary = [
        "" : ""
    ]

    print(parameters)

    ApiServices.requestPOSTURL(strURL, params: parameters, headers: headers, success:{

        (JSONResponse) -> Void in

        CommonMethodsClass.hideHUD(targetView: self.view)

        print(JSONResponse["message"])

        let strMsg = JSONResponse["message"].stringValue


        if (JSONResponse["status"].intValue == 1)
        {  

        }
        else
        {
            CommonMethodsClass.showAlertMessage(vc: self, titleStr: "Error!", messageStr: strMsg)
        }

    }) {
        (error) -> Void in
        print(error)

        CommonMethodsClass.hideHUD(targetView: self.view)
    }


// Api request method:
class func requestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : AnyObject]?, headers : [String : String]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){

    Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

        print(responseObject)

        if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value as Any)
            success(resJson)
        }
        if responseObject.result.isFailure {
            let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

> Error: FAILURE:
>   responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.}))

Update: Response to parse, may also needs to be changed.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "SalonID": "1",
            "SalonName": "Affinity",
            "SalonEmail": "vay.chaan@th-rce.com",
            "SalonPhone": "9999888877",
            "SalonMobile": "9999888877",
            "SalonAddress": "C-28, Sec-58, India",
            "Latitude": "18.5806",
            "Longitude": "27.36273",
            "Image": null,
            "SalonImage": "",
            "TimeIntervalminutes": 20,
            "AverageRating": 4,
            "IsActive": 1
        },
        {
            "SalonID": "3",
            "SalonName": "Looks",
            "SalonEmail": "rad@th-rce.com",
            "SalonPhone": "99998828877",
            "SalonMobile": "99998388877",
            "SalonAddress": "GP Mall,India",
            "Latitude": "",
            "Longitude": "",
            "Image": null,
            "SalonImage": "",
            "TimeIntervalminutes": 30,
            "AverageRating": 5,
            "IsActive": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: change `responseJSON` to `responseString`

Comment: but same code is working for another api

Comment: I think this API response is different than that API. That's why its not able to get. Alamofire found some suspicious value to the receiving type that's why it is giving this error.

Comment: Try responseString instead of responseJSON and it will work

Comment: yes, it's working strange. thanks

Comment: sure, but now it's parsing also not working "JSONResponse["data"].arrayValue"

Comment: do i need to change the way it parse also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `responseJSON` with `responseString`.

You need to convert the string for values. Can you update the string in your question?

You can use this function to convert response string into JSON:

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

String: `let str = "{\"name\":\"James\"}"`

USAGE:  `let dict = convertToDictionary(text: str)`

Comment: Please check question, now

Answer (score 1):

Try `responseString` instead of `responseJSON` and it will work

```
Alamofire.request("URL").responseString { response in
    print(response)

    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)")
    }
}
```

Comment: can you  please guide in parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Change responseJSON to responseString and it will work :)

```
  Alamofire.request("URL").responseString { response in
            print(response)

            if let json = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(json)")
            }
        }
```